# Check Robustness of ISI Q1 enlisted Journal?

Tags: publications, research-process, journals

Recently, I've received an acceptance for publishing my paper in an ISI enlisted Journal called Indian Journal of Science and Technology. Definitely, it's great.

How can I check the robustness of this journal? How much value will carry on it in academic world?

Can anyone help me, please?

http://www.indjst.org/index.php/indjst/index

Comment: **Check this before submitting**, not after your paper is accepted. This habit can only result in troubles and lots of wasted time for you, the editor, and the referees.

Comment: Exactly, but I am new in this are. That's why too many questions in my mind and bothering all of you...

Comment: Nop... my question is different than your suggested question and answer... @Sathyam

Comment: @tisuchi Please read the question correctly. The author had given the list of journals en ISI

Comment: yes.. I read. My question is not whether above journal is an ISI or not. I am talking about the robustness of my mentioned journal. TQ @Sathyam

Comment: I strongly suggest you follow the advice in the marked duplicate and judge the quality and impact of the journal for yourself, rather than relying on indexing services.

Comment: Are you sure this journal *is* ISI-listed? This journal does not seem to be in the ISI Journal Citation Reports, suggesting it isn't indexed. The Q scale, as the answer notes, is from SCImago, which is a different system.

Comment: ...and if it's not ISI-listed but claims it is, that's a pretty substantial red flag for its reliability/robustness

Comment: ohh... I see... But following link shows that this journal has enlisted with ISI ... Of course its not enlisted with Q Scale with ISI. @Andrew
http://ip-science.thomsonreuters.com/cgi-bin/jrnlst/jlresults.cgi?PC=MASTER&Full=Indian%20Journal%20of%20Science%20and%20Technology

Comment: Interesting - so it's not in the JCR, but it is indexed in one of the subsidary Web of Science collections ("Zoological Record"). This is borderline and not entirely wrong to describe it that way, but it wouldn't be how I'd normally define "ISI-indexed"

Comment: Ohh.... Now it is clear to me. Thank you for your clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q scale could be found for known journals, within the [SJR](http://www.scimagojr.com/) website...

As you can check [here](http://www.scimagojr.com/journalsearch.php?q=21100201522&tip=sid), this journal is a Q1 in 2014...

Best

Comment: Thank you. I saw this chart. But is that missing in 2015? It's SJR impact is 1.3. Does it good enough in-terms of evaluating my work?

Comment: It would be... The Q scale would often be computed sometime after the end of each year... You could, safely, consider the most up-to-date published Q scale for your further correspondences...

Comment: meaning... it has at least a good impact in academic world if it will be published in this journal, isnt it?

Comment: Yeah, It could be... Furthermore, you could be roughly sure that a Q1 journal in 2014 will not drop off, considerably, within the upcoming year...

Comment: Huh... that's really great.

Thank you all for your valuable comments..

Comment: Good luck, buddy...